# Is a pointer to the return-value of the typeid operator always valid in C++?

Tags: c++, typeid

I assume it is the case, because e.g. &typeid(int) should be known already at compile-time, i.e. the pointer should never be invalidated when running out of any scope.

**Example:**
If my assumption is correct, then the following code should not lead to any undefined behavior (at least it works on my PC).

```
int main() {
    const std::type_info* pType = nullptr; 
    {
        pType = &typeid(int);
    }
    std::cout << pType->name() << std::endl;
}
```

**My goal:**
Let's say I have a class called MyTest defined as follows.

```
struct MyTest {
    const std::type_info* pType;
    MyTest(const std::type_info& type) : pType(&type) {}
    void printType() { std::cout << pType->name() << std::endl; }
};
```

Then the following code should hopefully lead to no undefined behavior, even when the argument in the constructor of MyTest is just "local".

```
int main() {
    MyTest myTest(typeid(double));
    myTest.printType();
}
```

I know there is another thread about whether you can compare two types by comparing the pointers to the return value of typeid, but that is not my problem here.

Comment: Note: that those strings aren't guaranteed to be particularly useful. Implementors do their best to make sure they are mostly useful, but your mileage will vary when you do weird stuff or have to use a shoddy toolchain.

Comment: Thanks @user4581301. I know that the return value of pType->name() depends on the implementation. The example above is just a much more simplified version of my actual code.

Comment: Understood. The comment is for you if you need it and any askers that find the question in the future. My concern isn't so much with the differences in the strings from implementation to implementation, it's with the lack of a guarantee of uniqueness. Multiple types can share the same ID string, a truly nasty shock when you trip over it unaware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the current draft of the Standard, that's safe.  Two key points found in `[expr.typeid]`:

> - The result of a typeid expression is an lvalue .
> - The lifetime of the object referred to by the lvalue extends to the end of the program

https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.typeid#1

Answer (score 2):

This is safe.  From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid):

> The typeid expression is an lvalue expression which refers to an object with static storage duration, of const-qualified version of the polymorphic type std::type_info or some type derived from it.

Since the object has static storage duration is is guaranteed to live until the end of `main`

Comment: Thanks! I suspected that it is working exactly the way you have described, although I had to ask to be absolutely sure that it will not break my code.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the quoted language from the standard in the other answers I suspect there are some cases where other actions would make this invalid.

Say that you have: `polymorphic_type * some_function();` in a dynamically-loaded library, you load the library and call the function `polymorphic_type * pPoly { some_function() };` (getting a valid `polymorphic_type *`) but then unload the library without invalidating the pointer. You then do a `&typeid(pPoly)`. Your code will likely try getting type information from invalid memory.

This is, of course, highly contrived, but AFAIK the standard doesn't actually say anything about how object files are formatted or how executables are actually run.

Comment: Unloading of libraries in a way that removes them from address space can't be compatible with the standard anyway, because it messes with lifetime of all static storage duration objects and with function pointer values in ways that ought to be impossible with the semantics of the standard.

Comment: Sure, like I said 'contrived'. I was just pointing out that if the argument is not actually a statically-determined type then the operation can depend on bits not strictly part of the object.